# "SQL" menu for SSDT is disappeared in VS 2013 after SSDT update

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

I installed [last update](http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/8/8/D8831A15-0114-4DDE-B248-49DE51DC3922/Dev12/EN/SSDTSetup.exe) of **SSDT for VS 2013** and **SQL** menu is gone!

Answer (score 3):

The **SQL** menu is moved under **Tools** menu as **SQL Server**.

[image]